# Convert a 5 pin Elno connector to a 3 pin XLR

Tags: audio, connector, microphone, diy, xlr

I'm trying to modify a Elno laryngophone's connector (5 pin) to plug like a normal mic so I need to understand how to wire cable to a standard XLR connector, maybe somebody knows how to do? thank you

[image: 5 pin connector][image: laryngophone]

Comment: Somebody would need to know the pinout. What is the intention to convert it to standard 3-pin XLR? These are used for multiple thing by multiple manufacturers, should we assume you want to connect to an analog mic or line input? If the 5-pin connector needs power, the 3-pin XLR can't provide it. Unless mic input provides phantom power and it is converted to be suitable. This may not be possible to replace with just soldering wires.

Comment: thank you @Justme The brand of this laryngophone is Elno but on the web I haven't found any diagram that shows the function of the various pins.. what I would like to do is to change connector to a XLR (if possible) and then plug it to a mixer (where I have also phantom power if needed)